# What could be the reason that this transistor gets too hot unexpectedly?

Tags: transistors, temperature, datasheet

In the following circuit, for the transistor it can be calculated that: Vce=4.5V and Ic=170mA. I also implemented this on breadboard and measured almost the same quantities.

[image]

The opamp is an LM324 and the NPN transistor datasheet is [here](https://docs.rs-online.com/abfd/0900766b80dafa99.pdf).

Here is the photo of the transistor:

[image]

The transistor power in the circuit above must be P=VcexIc.  This becomes 4.5V x 0.18A which is less than 1W power.

In the transistor datasheet the thermal resistance is given as 10 degrees per Watt. So in my case I expect not more than 10 C increase. The room temperature is 25 C and I expect 35 C for the tansistor surface.

But when I touch with my finger it feels like it is very hot like 100 C. Is my interpretation of the temperature wrong or is my expectation is wrong? Why does it get hot that much?

Comment: That's the junction-case thermal resistance. So however hot you let the case get, the junction is 10C hotter (at 1W). I think you forgot the heatsink.

Comment: @BrianDrummond But how can the junction temperature be calculated and how can I know whether I need heatsink?

Comment: Just to comment: you can't touch 100°C. It'll burn you immediately. Even 70°C is dangerous.  https://i.imgur.com/mj7szFc.png     So if you even remotely touched it and it ***feels*** hot, and you weren't burned: the temperature is within the specs. This transistor can work at up to 125°C without issues.

Comment: @NatsuKage Another thing I observed is that IR thermometer is unable measure its temperature for some reason it shows it is 25 C but it cant be it really feels ouch..

Comment: Feels ouch as in you immediately have burnt white skin and had to apply ointments or cold water? You are definitely in a usable range if it just feels ouch. xD

Comment: No I didn’t need even I touched several times less than a second. I left the circuit for 10 minutes it was still working.   If it gets damaged due to over heat does it happpen immediately???

Comment: @ty_1917 If you really want to measure it with a IR thermometer you need to paint it black. If it worked 10min then it should be fine. But even the smallest heatsink will prevent failure if it's in a closed environment with no airflow.

Comment: @NatsuKage, 100°C will not burn you immediately if you touch the hot item  ... it will hurt, but whether it will cause damage depends on other factors

Comment: @jsotola I'm just stating stuff from wiki sources. I'm not going to prove this anytime soon. xD  "At 70° C (185° F) or greater, the exposure time required to cause trans-epidermal necrosis is less than 1 second"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_burn#cite_note-path-14

Comment: The sole reason why this transistor got too hot **unexpectedly** is the fact that the expectations were not realistic.

Comment: It's probably not even close to 100 °C. This is when the thermalcoupler temperature measurement on a multimeter comes handy.

Comment: _"Just to comment: you can't touch 100°C. It'll burn you immediately."_ - Sure you can, just briefly. And no, it won't, not immediately. For comparison, I can touch food and the rack in my oven at about 200°C, just very very briefly. If you can keep your finger on it for one whole second, I'll agree it's very likely below 100°C. But saying you couldn't touch something at 100°C is a bit imprecise. You should also consider the thermal mass of the transistor, which is pretty small (which is why people can "pinch out" candle flames).

Comment: @NatsuKage The chart shows the temperature of your finger, not the temperature of the thing you're touching.

Comment: The only time I get instant burns is when I touch my soldering iron at 400 °C, then my skin is white immediately. If I touch a metal piece in the oven which is at 200 °C I see it the day after as a red streak. I do this regularly.

Comment: You'll retract your touch from a too hot item far quicker than in one second. However, food from a 200°C oven is unlikely to be a literal 200°C hot (apart from a very thin surface layer maybe) unless you managed charring it thoroughly.... a water bearing thermal mass has a hard time getting much above 100°C. Anything very dry and mostly based on fat and starch would also be smoking....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How to know if you need a heatsink. (Apart from the burnt finger).

This is well covered in engineering textbooks and courses. [And websites such as this](https://www.giangrandi.org/electronics/thcalc/thcalc.shtml).

In short :

You know the power dissipation, and the ambient temperature where this lives. Let's say, 1W, and 40C.

You decide what temperature you want to restrict the junction to : below 100C, lets say 90C for a safety margin.

From the Junction-Case thermal resistance (10C/W) and the power (1W), that gives a case temp of 80C (or 40C above ambient).

Which means we need 40C/watt between case and air.
(If the 62K/W figure is correct for a SOT32 package ... google it ... you need a heatsink.

So we look for a heatsink with 40C/watt or better, thermal resistance.

(This is slightly simplified to illustrate the principle, but good enough for this application. For more detailed thermal budgeting, see e.g. the website above)

---

Damage can take microseconds to years, depending on the degree of overheating.

Comment: Very comprehensive thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I have never seen any package get remotely close to 10K/W without a heatsink. It's usually more like 62K/W, even for a large package. Smaller packages like SOICs can be double that, and SOTs can be four times that and it doesn't really change all that much with more exposed metal surfaces. You have to mount heatsinks to make use of those surfaces.

You have to read the subscripts and fine-print in the datasheet. 10K/W is the junction-to-case thermal resistance and is used in heatsink calculations. Junction-to-ambient is what is important if you are not using a heatsink.

How much easier life would be if we could get numbers as low as 10K/W junction-to-ambient.

Comment: Im very confused how can I know whether I need heatsink?:(

Comment: Your sore finger tells you that :-)

Comment: @ty_1917 That datasheet doesn't list junction to ambient thermal resistance which is real crappy. But you can probably get a reasonably accurate number if you look at other chips in the same package. You are approaching 1W, so you need a heatsink. 62~65K/W tends to be the number for large packages with heatsink tabs which means at more than 0.5W it will burn your finger. 50-60C is its too hot for the skin. Smaller packages like SOICs and SOTs can easily be four times that junction-to-ambient thermal resistance.

Answer (score 3):

The 10°C/W in your datasheet is from the junction to the case. For a transistor sitting in the air with no heat-sink, the thermal resistance from case to ambient will usually be much higher than the thermal resistance from junction to case.

Unfortunately the data sheet for your particular transistor does not talk about the thermal resistance from junction to ambient, or from case to ambient but picking another transistor in the same case style ( http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/43630.pdf ) suggests the junction to ambient thermal resistance will be about 100°C/W

So if your ambient temperature is 30°C and you are dissipating 1W, then the junction temperature would be expected to be about 130°C and the case temperature about 120°C

Which is pretty hot, but it's within then 150°C maximum junction temperature rating of your transistor.

P.S. Even with a heat-sink it is generally impractical to actually achieve the nominal rating of a transistor. With your transistor achieving the nominal rating requires a case temperature of 25°C which is wildly impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to follow up in comment:

> Im very confused how can I know whether I need heatsink?:(

assume something between ~5W/(m^2 K) thermal conductance to be on the safe side (respectively please look it up in a thermal engineering handbook for the non-safe side and in general). Should be specified with the cooling fins hwn you buy them.

So a 100cm^2 cooling surface will have .05W/K -> 20K DeltaT per W

Comment: It sounds like you are describing characteristics of a heatsink. This does not answer the question...how does the OP know if they **need** a heatsink.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: i woul also assume a similar value for the surface of the transistor itself.

Comment: That would be a very poor assumption, in my opinion, given that the materials and assembly styles vary greatly from one transistor to another. That's why manufacturers provide values of \$\Theta_{CA}\$ and \$\Theta_{CS}\$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see some bypassing capacitors and filter capacitors across the inputs outputs and control lines. You may have some unintended oscillations going on  maybe RF that you are unaware of. This would dramatically increase the transistors dissipated power.

Answer (score 0):

IR thermometers are easily tricked by reflective surfaces. Use black tape or flat black paint or a contact thermometer. Dull black surfaces should cause your IR thermometer to be within 5%. Use a scope to check for oscillations and add bypassing because the scope probe may be enough to kill the oscillations that you're looking for.

Comment: Scotch 88 is my go-to for temperature readings. It has an emissivity of 0.96 in both MWIR and LWIR bands:  https://www.flir.com/discover/rd-science/use-low-cost-materials-to-increase-target-emissivity/

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the reason that this transistor gets too hot unexpectedly?

**Mathematical Reason = V * I * Rca = Trise [Rca='C/W of case]**
(Power Law * Thermal resistance,Rca case-ambient)

Engineers must learn what the thermodynamic resistance and resulting temperature rise and air-flow velocity factors that affect this. (from 0 to 5 m/s)

For example, a 1/4 W leaded resistor dissipating 1/4W at room temp of 25'C will rise to ___ what temperature ? (**hint**: lookup temp. de-rating curve in datasheet)

There are **rules of thumb** to remember , and when you burn your finger from 1/4W, maybe you will never forget. ;)

1) Consider 2 square inches (6 cm^2) of metallic surface per watt or 1sq.in. double-sided Cu heat dissipation or high density surface finned heatsink for semiconductors, for a 40'C rise above 40'C ambient. But Resistors can run hotter.

2) Choose a heatsink rated for more than 50% of your power supply for efficiency reasons.

3) Consider more efficient designs in future.

4) Understand what is needed for electrical insulation, if required

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In engineering it is important to learn to get a feeling for proportions. If you just go to your preferred electronic parts shop and look at some heatsinks, you'll quickly learn what 10 K/W actually means regarding ambient air. E.g, https://www.conrad.nl/p/fischer-elektronik-ick-pga-14-x-14-x-14-koellichaam-96-kw-l-x-b-x-h-35-x-35-x-14-mm-181177
is a 9.6 K/W heat sink, measuring 35x35x14 mm, way bigger than your naked transistor.[image: heatsink 10K/W measuring 35mm]

What this tells you is that it is easy to transfer some excess heat through 1 mm of a metal plate (transistor substrate) but much harder to transfer it to the ambient air. Air is rather a thermal insulator, unless it moves, hence fans.

Back to your question, you'll need quite some big fins for even just 1 lousy watt of heat, if you deal with stuff that can't stand high temperatures. Case in point, a 1 W lamp (bulb) is no big deal because it can handle hundreds of C. The classic bicycle front lamp was 2.5W. But a 1 W led needs serious cooling, just like your transistor.

Answer (score -1):

Surprising nobody picked up your basic calculation error. You say VCE is 4.5V then you say IC is 170mA? Yet you have a 2.5ohm resistor with 4.5v across it?

Comment: @Shooter_McGavin Love the username, but not sure your answer provides much insight into the question, and I am not sure what you are correcting? It would work out that the transistor drops ~4.5V with 170mA current given the 25 Ohm load...

Comment: The BJT is in linear mode, not as a switch.

Comment: @MadHatter The transistor is in series with a 2.5 ohm load and together they have 9 volts across them. If the Vce is 4.5V then the voltage across the load is 9V - 4.5V = 4.5V.

Comment: However, this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Not 2.5 ohm, I see no dec.point, hence 25 ohm; times 170 mA = 4.25 V, no problem :-)